# Предложение для возможности "понять о чём была речь в беседе под вопросом/ответом, спустя время и правки"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Суть предложения.

Есть вопрос или ответ под которым можно вести переписку. Однако с течением времени они могут быть изменены и тогда, при последующем чтении, смысл некоторых поясняющих сообщений внизу от других пользователей может быть искажён. В связи с этим было бы неплохо иметь возможность, при наведении на сообщение пользователя в переписке, переходить на то состояние вопроса, во время которого было написано пояснение от этого пользователя.

Comment: Комментарии — это временная штука; после завершения обсуждения, решения упомянутых в них вопросов и внесения правок они должны быть удалены как переставшие быть необходимыми (если они не удалены, следует нажать тревогу с причиной «больше не нужен», чтобы модераторы удалили). Как следствие, данное предложение не имеет смысла.

Comment: Порой обсуждения могут длиться неделями, а то и месяцами, пока будет выработано окончательное решение.

Comment: @andreymal: Формально вы правы. Фактически же очень часто комментарии служат дополнительным, важным источником информации, поскольку участникам лень конвертировать обсуждение в осмысленный, литературно оформленный текст, и размещать его в ответе. C’est la vie.

Comment: @VladD, ну если комментарий актуален и при этом непонятно, к чему он относится, то вряд ли проблема в версии сообщения, под которым он расположен. Скорее в том, что кто-то соседний комментарий удалил.

Answer (score 3):

В подобных ситуациях мне всегда хватало открытия списка изменений и просмотра истории. Прям точно определять версию на момент комментария обычно не требуется.

Есть другая проблема - один из переписывающихся комментарии снёс, а ты читаешь второго и не понимаешь, на что он вообще отвечает. Но, насколько я понимаю, доступность удалённых комментариев и истории правок комментариев только модераторам сделана намеренно и никто это изменять не станет.